# Foreach loop with a global macro that constitutes other global macros

Tags: loops, foreach, stata, stata-macros

I want to shorten the following code. How do I go about it? In essence, I would like to create another global called `total_wardlist` that would have the global macros mentioned below: i.e. `wardlist_01`, `wardlist_02`, `wardlist_03` and `wardlist_04`.

```
foreach x of global wardlist_01{
        display "Checking for `x'"
        replace name_colony6_wardname = "`x'" if (strpos(name_colony6, "`x'") > 0)
    }
    
    
    foreach x of global wardlist_02{
        display "Checking for `x'"
        replace name_colony6_wardname = "`x'" if (strpos(name_colony6, "`x'") > 0)
    }
    
    
    foreach x of global wardlist_03{
        display "Checking for `x'"
        replace name_colony6_wardname = "`x'" if (strpos(name_colony6, "`x'") > 0)
    }
    
    
    foreach x of global wardlist_04{
        display "Checking for `x'"
        replace name_colony6_wardname = "`x'" if (strpos(name_colony6, "`x'") > 0)
    }
    
    foreach x of global wardlist_05{
        display "Checking for `x'"
        replace name_colony6_wardname = "`x'" if (strpos(name_colony6, "`x'") > 0)
    }
```

I tried the following code but it returns "0 real changes made" when there should have been changes. Please advise.

```
global total_wardlist wardlist_01 wardlist_02 wardlist_03 wardlist_04 wardlist_05
foreach x of global $total_wardlist{
        display "Checking for `$x'"
        replace name_colony6_wardname = "`$x'" if (strpos(name_colony5, "`$x'") > 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's set aside a widespread aversion to and avoidance of global macros by experienced Stata programmers. General advice is to use local macros to the maximum extent possible.

You could loop over those macros:

```
forval g = 1/4 { 

foreach x of global wardlist_0`g' {
        display "Checking for `x'"
        replace name_colony6_wardname = "`x'" if (strpos(name_colony6, "`x'") > 0)
}

}
```

If you preferred that, I would indent the inner loop.

Or you could combine them first:

```
global total_wardlist $wardlist_01 $wardlist_02 $wardlist_03 $wardlist_04 

foreach x of global total_wardlist {
        display "Checking for `x'"
        replace name_colony6_wardname = "`x'" if (strpos(name_colony6, "`x'") > 0)
}
```

Code not checked, but fairly confident. The second solution shows up two kinds of errors in your attempted code.